# how to remove folder lock option in the context menu?

Tags: windows-7

Some days ago I installed Folder Lock in my computer. Then I uninstalled it but the item "Lock file with Folder Lock" still remains in the right-click (context) menu. How can it be removed?

Answer (score 4):

there are a lot of places in the registry that hold the right click context menu.

Using an external program, such as [Shell Menu View](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shell_menu_view.html) will give you the safest way to enable/disable context menu items.

If you do want to look in the registry, I would refer you to this page, to give you an idea of the work that's involved:
http://windowsxp.mvps.org/context_folders.htm

Comment: Nice tip. ShellMenuView really could have come in handy recently. I even already had a copy of ShellMenuView, but I never even noticed because I always use ShellExView instead. I’ll be sure to keep it in mind next time. `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

If your'e using CCleaner try running the Registry fixer, it can remove it if the file the entry is pointing to has been removed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to uninstall all the stuff of folder lock then I'll suggest you to just install it again and download [Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/) and then uninstall through it. It will  delete all registry keys and other hide folders which have been created by this software(folder lock).